# Is it possible to remove PDF's images and only keep the OCR'd text?

Tags: macos, pdf, ocr, abbyy

I scanned a book and OCR'd it using [ABBYYY](https://pdf.abbyy.com/) but all I really care about is the text from the OCR and that it's organized by page. Is there a tool I could use to drop all of the scanned page images but keep all of the OCR text? I realize it wouldn't be human readable at that point, but that's ok because I'm processing the PDF with Python scripts.

Comment: You could use Ghostscipt to produce a new PDF file with no image data. Use the pdfwrite device and specify -dFILTERIMAGE, that will cause the interpreter to drop all limage data in the output. https://ghostscript.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Use.html#dfilterimage

Comment: You can try `cpdf -draft in.pdf -o out.pdf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@johnwhitington's comment to the question worked great for me.  but it's not a complete answer.

`cpdf -draft in.pdf -o out.pdf`

you can get cpdf from https://github.com/coherentgraphics/cpdf-binaries

the `-draft` option removes images:

```
  -draft Remove images from the file
```

You need to make sure you actually have text in the file first, of course - with Acrobat, that's the `editable text and images` option in the OCR settings - if you can copy a block of text and paste it outside and get readable text, you might have a pdf that works for this.

This produces a perfectly human readable result (minus any supporting graphics, obviously).

further information and documentation on the cpdf tool can be found at:

https://www.coherentpdf.com
https://www.coherentpdf.com/cpdfmanual.pdf

you may find a combination of `-draft AND -blacktext` useful (I did)